# Plotting relative to a fixed data element

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following datafile:

```
x  y
 1 50.583
 2 27.842
 3 19.156                                                              
 4 15.491
 6  9.779
 8  8.584                                                              
12  6.436                                                              
16  4.595
24  3.605
32  2.447
```

I want to plot the points (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub> / y<sub>1</sub>). How do I do this using gnuplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution using shell scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
base=`head -n1 input.txt | cut -f2 -d' '`
gnuplot << EOF
plot input.txt using 1:(\$2 / $base)
EOF
```